# C: Function returning via void *

Tags: c, memory, pointers, malloc, void-pointers

Coming from Java I'm confused by the use of Void allowing a return value in the following:

```
void *emalloc(size_t s) {  
    void *result = malloc(s);  
    if (NULL == result) {  
        fprintf(stderr, "MEMORY ALLOCATION FAILURE\n");  
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  
    }  
    return result;  
}
```

Is this returning a pointer to a chuck of allocated of memory ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it is. A void* pointer is basically a generic pointer to a memory address, which could then typically be typecast to whatever type was actually desired.

Comment: A void * may always be converted to an object pointer, but not necessarily to a function pointer.  The reliability of that conversion is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 9):

Your question indicates that you are misreading the function's return type.  There is a big difference between:

```
void foo( void ) {}
```

and

```
void *bar( void ) {}
```

foo() takes no arguments and does not return a value, while bar() takes no arguments and returns a generic pointer.  In C, the keyword void is used to indicate a generic pointer, and an object of type void * can be converted to any other object pointer type without loss of information.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this function is returning a pointer to allocated memory of a specified size.  It's different in malloc in the sense that it's guaranteed to return a pointer.  On failure it will exit the application.

Comment: You sure about that? C++'s `new` operator throws but AFAIK the standard C malloc can return `NULL` on error.

Comment: I see, you mean "it's different *from* `malloc`" (referring to this `emalloc` example) - thought you were referring to `malloc` itself.

Comment: @Earwicker: malloc can return NULL, but emalloc cannot.  If it can't get memory, the program exits and emalloc does not return.

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but is emalloc() a standard function ?

Comment: this is just a malloc wrapper to move the error handling for malloc from the caller to the callee.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  `void*` meaning pointer to something, but of no particular type.

Answer (score 2):

In Java there is no pointer arithmetic. It think this is what you are asking about. For example, imagine that `malloc` returns a pointer of type `int`

```
int* malloc(size_t size)
{
    //
}
```

You would possibly receive the pointer, which is basically a pointer to an `array`. Then you would index it like regular arrays.

```
int* arr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); // 10 contiguous int(s).
```

The problem is that `C` doesn't have functions overloading. So, we have to find a way to write a generic `malloc`. Otherwise, you would end up with a different `malloc` for every type. The solution, is to send the required number of bytes that you need. Then, you can index it however you like. This gives a greater flexibility and one for all solution.

```
int*  i = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); // 40 bytes if int = 4 bytes
char* c = (char*)malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // 10 bytes if char = 1 byte

int  thirdElement = i[3]; // third element. 12 bytes away from (*i)
char secondElement = c[2]; // second element. 2 bytes away from (*c)
```

So, the whole idea is that it doesn't matter how we index the memory we got from `malloc`. All what we have to do is to specify the type of the newly created array to index it properly.  `void*` means that this is a pointer to place in memory that we haven't specified how to index.

Answer (score 2):

void means essentially no type, so if we have void *p; p is a pointer to something, but we haven't said what.

void without a pointer is nothing hence void foo(void) being a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing.

And yes malloc returns a pointer to some chunk of memory, malloc doesn't know or care what type that memory has, so it's return type is void*